# How do I make sure a role is run host A before running a task on host B?

Tags: ansible

Lets say I want to setup 1) Apache webserver and 2) a repository of Tarballs on host A and then download those tarballs over http in some tasks on host B. How would I set up that dependency in Ansible?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly but do you want to execute ansible-playbook for your whole infrastructure and you want to be sure about order executed roles?

Comment: Yes that’s right but note in particular there are dependencies between hosts.

Comment: Dependencies between hosts not between groups, right?

Comment: Well i suppose groups would be more useful. You can always have a group of one host!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can create two playbook files:

**hosts-A.yml**

```
---

- hosts: hosts-A
  gather_facts: yes

  roles:
    - { role: apache }
    - { role: repo_of_tarballs }
```

**hosts-B.yml**

```
---

- hosts: hosts-B
  gather_facts: yes

  roles:
    - { role: download_tarballs }
```

Afterwards you can create a **site.yml** file which will be contains:

```
---

- import_playbook: hosts-A.yml
- import_playbook: hosts-B.yml
```

To execute playbook: `ansible-playbook site.yml`

Comment: Ah so basically to satisfy a dependency between hosts you setup two playbooks to execute sequentially. Playbook imports are executed in the order they listed.

Comment: In my opinion it's a simplest solution. What do you think about it?

Comment: I have justed started using ansible, but I also think this is a simple solution. I will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Does everything I need. Thanks!